# Cannot pull due to info.plist error: "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." in Xcode 10.3

Tags: xcode, swift4, plist, xcode10

We have recently updated to Swift 4 and upgraded our xCode version and have had a myriad of issues including this info.plist problem. Every time we try to pull changes through xCode we get an error stating the info.plist file is not in the correct format.

[See file in question here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHOld.png)
Digging into the info.plist file we see that it has lines around the GitCommit key (`<<<<<<<<< HEAD` and `>>>>>>>>>>BRANCH`) for the merge conflict. Opening it with VSCode I can resolve the conflict with the file and continue with the pull, but it is frustrating to have to open another IDE, find the file, correct it, and go back to xCode. In xCode 9.4 the info.plist conflicts worked fine and we just had to select the most recent GitCommit but we can't even see the file in xCode 10.3. Any suggestions on permanent fixes for this would be appreciated!

Comment: I don’t get it. You had a merge conflict. Resolve it

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly two things to try (tested in Xcode 10.1):

1. Right-click the plist in Xcode and select "Open in External Editor". That should open the file in a suitable text editor and you can resolve the merge conflict, save, and then return to Xcode
2. Select the plist in Xcode and dismiss the error alert. On the right side of Xcode (usually) select the File Inspector and change the file type to "XML" or "Plain Text". Xcode will now show the raw XML and you can resolve the merge conflict. Then change the file type back to "Property List XML" – you may need to use  "File > Close" in Xcode to persuade Xcode to reload the file using its plist editor.

HTH